# C++ Forward Declare Struct In .h File and Define Struct In The .cpp File

Tags: c++

I'm looking to forward declare a struct in a header and then hide the implementation in the source file.

mystruct.h

```
...

struct MyStruct;

...
```

mystruct.cpp

```
#include <mystruct.h>
...

struct MyStruct : virtual SomeOtherStruct, virtual AndAnotherStruct {};

...
```

However when I try to instantiate MyStruct:

main.cpp

```
#include <mystruct.h>
...

MyStruct structTest;

...
```

I get the error

> "error: aggregate 'MyStruct structTest' has incomplete type and cannot
>   be defined"

How can I declare a structure in the header and then define it later in the source? It's important that `MyStruct` inherits from other structures. I would like to hide as much implementation detail as possible.

Comment: You can't do that. `main.cpp` must have access to the struct's definition. You could hide implementation by using the *pimpl* idiom.

Comment: How could the compiler know the object layout of MyStruct within main.cpp? Remember that only at link time the different compilation units are brought together, so from the perspective of the compiler, main.cpp is completely unrelated to mystruct.cpp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a pointer to the struct. However, you cannot use a value of type MyStruct, because the compiler doesn't know the size/layout of the struct without the struct definition.  Since the struct definition is hidden in the .cpp file (and is thus not "visible" when the compiler is processing main.cpp):

```
MyStruct* structTest;
```

is allowed in your main.cpp, whereas

```
 MyStruct structTest;
```

is not.  Additionally, something like:

```
void foo() {
    MyStruct* test;
    test->someFunc();
}
```

won't compile if it's put in main.cpp, for the same reason.  You should put the struct definition in the header, or use PIMPL, as one of the other commenters noted.